# Make easier to use $\C$ for complex numbers: clashes with T2A, mismath, and babel

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, packages, babel, font-encodings

My strong preference is to use `$\C$` to denote the set of complex numbers, just as I use `$\R$` to denote the real numbers — whether with `\mathbb` or `\mathbf`.

Several other packages use their own definitions of `\C`: `t2aenc.def` (called from `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}`); `mismath.sty`; and either `hyperref.sty` or some package it calls.

My workaround for this shown in the MWE below.

*Question:* Is there a simpler method to accomplish this — without repeatedly redefining `\C`?

*Notes:*

- It is very unlikely I'll ever need the `\C` from `babel`'s use of T2A. I'm unsure of how `hyperref` uses `\C`. (It's for a double-grave accent in Serbo-Croatian and Slovenian.)
- I am using pdflatex and *not* xelatex or lualatex!

*Source MWE:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,french,german,polish,main=english]{babel}

% Avoid \lll clash with def in amssymb.sty:
\makeatletter
    \let\polish@l=\ll
    \let\polish@L=\LLL
    \let\lll\relax \let\LLL\relax % undefine them
    \def\plll{\polish@l}
    \def\pLLL{\polish@L}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Choose ONE of the following two defs:
%\newcommand{\numsys}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\numsys}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

% First 
\makeatletter
\def\my@textormath{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
    \ifcsname C\endcsname
      \let\oldC\C
      \def\C{\my@textormath{\oldC}{\numsys{C}}}
    \fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{mismath} % defines \Z, \Z, \Q, \R, \C with mathbf

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\my@textormath{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{% then
    \let\newerC\C
    \def\C{\my@textormath{\newerC}{\numsys{C}}}}%
  {}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\N}{\numsys{N}}
\renewcommand{\Z}{\numsys{Z}}
\renewcommand{\Q}{\numsys{Q}}
\renewcommand{\R}{\numsys{R}}

\begin{document}

$\N \subset \Z \subset \Q \subset \R \subset \C$

\end{document}
```

*Related post:* [Possible to use$ \C$ for complex numbers with T2A encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494733/possible-to-use-c-for-complex-numbers-with-t2a-encoding)

Comment: If you want your definition to win do as late as possible `\AtBeginDocument{\def\C{\numsys{C}}}`.

Comment: I *do* want mine to win, and this works! Please make as an answer. (Do you happen to know how/where the \C is used by hypreref, just in case I'm overlooking something I might actually need there?)

Comment: hyperref adds a definition for the accent command for the bookmarks. if you don't need the command in this sense, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your definition to win add as late as possible

```
  \AtBeginDocument{\def\C{\numsys{C}}}
```